# View Excel File then send with Email Message

Tags: c#, .net, excel, email

I am creating a web application that will allow my users to edit an excel like gridview.

There are two buttons that I incorporated that will send an email with an attached excel file and also a button that will display the excel file being sent.

The problem with the two is that on requesting to just view the file it displays fine locally but when pushed to my web server it doesn't work at all.

With the other button to send the file as an attachment in an email it will not attach but it will send the email.

here is the code to send the email:

```
 try
            {
                const string attachment = "summary.xlsx";
                var mail = new MailMessage();

                mail.To.Add("Tester@test.com");
                mail.From = new MailAddress("Tester@test.com");
                mail.Subject = "SummarySpreadsheet " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
                mail.Body = "Hello Everyone," + "\n" + "\n" +
                            "Attached is the Spreadsheet for your review." + "\n" + "\n" +
                            "Thank you!" + "\n" + "\n";
                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Server.MapPath("//testserver/apps/testApp/Daily/summary.xlsx")));


                var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("test.test.com");  //this is fake
                smtpClient.Send(mail);
                Response.Write("Email Sent Successfully!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Could not send the email - error" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Here is the code I used to just view the spreadsheet:

```
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"\\testserver\apps\testApp\Daily\summary.xlsx");
```

I have done my research and found lots of ways to send emails with attachments and they work locally but when pushed to my server nothing works. I have copied dll's over and made sure everything was consistent but still no change.

Any help on this would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was able to solve my problem.

1. in regards to opening the file client side I had to use this code (I was going about it server side): `location.href='_summary.xlsx';return false;`
2. and in regards to the emailing I used a `stream` and `File.OpenRead("file location")` to get it to send correctly.